# validate form then open mail program

Tags: javascript, html, web

Is there away to validate a form in js and if its valid execute a js function?

basiclly it should check if the form is valid then open the default email program with some entries

like so ->

[image: like so]

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can

```js
$('#loginform').validate({
    rules: {
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true,
            maxlength: 30
        },
        password: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 8,
            maxlength: 20,
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) { // for demo
        return false; // for demo
    }
});



$("#submit").click(function() {
    if ($('#loginform').valid()) {
     alert("Open mail program");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.2/jquery.validate.min.js" integrity="sha256-+BEKmIvQ6IsL8sHcvidtDrNOdZO3C9LtFPtF2H0dOHI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<form id="loginform">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="form-control form-control-lg" id="email" 
                                   name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email" autocomplete="off">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="form-control form-control-lg" id="password" name="password"
                                   type="password" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                        <button type="button" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Login </button>
                    </form>
```